# how to update ubuntu os off usb (boot mode)

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 and I am running 64bit and it does not run well on my old laptop, I have downloaded the 32bit version and have made a U.S.B. disk, I just don't know what to do from now. How do I boot it from the U.S.B. drive? I have tried hitting all the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys on boot up but this does nothing.

Comment: I assume you mean 64 bit and 32 bit (if so please edit to change).  If so, then you can't just upgrade, you have to reinstall completely.  Just do it the same way you did the first time.

Comment: Yes sorry i did mean 32bit and i do need to reinstall but last time i did it i was running windows 8 now i only run Ubuntu and i dont know how to do this i have made the new start up drive but i do not know how to run it Thanks